# Multiple exists vs union

Tags: mysql

If I want to get a boolean value 1 if the id is in one of the tables, and 0 if its not, what is the best / fastest way?

A: 2 Exists with OR

```
SELECT 
    EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM a WHERE id = 1) 
    OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE id = 1)
```

B: 1 Exists with UNION

```
SELECT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM a WHERE id = 1
    UNION
    SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE id = 1)
```

C: Union with Limit

```
    SELECT 1 FROM a WHERE id = 1
    UNION
    SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE id = 1
    UNION
    SELECT 0
    LIMIT 1
```

If you have a way better then my 3 solutions, please write it too.

DESCRIBES:

A:

```
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra          |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | NULL  | NULL  | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  | NULL | No tables used |
|    3 | SUBQUERY    | a     | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 | Using index    |
|    2 | SUBQUERY    | b     | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 | Using index    |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------------+
```

B:

```
+------+--------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------------+
| id   | select_type  | table      | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra          |
+------+--------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | NULL       | NULL  | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  | NULL | No tables used |
|    2 | SUBQUERY     | a          | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 | Using index    |
|    3 | UNION        | b          | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 | Using index    |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union2,3> | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  | NULL |                |
+------+--------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------------+
```

C:

```
+------+--------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------------+
| id   | select_type  | table        | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra          |
+------+--------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | a            | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 | Using index    |
|    2 | UNION        | b            | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 | Using index    |
|    3 | UNION        | NULL         | NULL  | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  | NULL | No tables used |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union1,2,3> | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  | NULL |                |
+------+--------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe D (not tested):

```
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT 1 FROM a,b WHERE a.id=1 OR b.id=1 LIMIT 1),0)
```

Comment: "Using join buffer" sounds expensive